# Phonegap create build for windows mobile from Mac OSX

Tags: windows, cordova, build, msbuild, phonegap-cli

I am working on PhoneGap app.

I am done with iOS & Android platform for my app.

i did use XCode & Android Studio for create build for both.

But I am struggling with Windows platform for create app for windows.

I have tried below things via Terminal:

```
phonegap platform remove windows
phonegap local build windows
[warning] The command `phonegap local <command>` has been DEPRECATED.
[warning] The command has been delegated to `phonegap <command>`.
[warning] The command `phonegap local <command>` will soon be removed.
[phonegap] executing 'cordova platform add --save windows' ...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova platform add --save windows'
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build windows ' ...
The following navigation rule had an invalid URI scheme and is ignored: "*".


Error: No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target.


phonegap remote build windows
[phonegap] compressing the app...
[phonegap] uploading the app...
   [error] {"error":"app 2270357 not found"}
   [error]
```

So, i am unable to create build Locally or via remote for windows platform.

Please help me regarding it.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried many different methods to build Windows platform and troubleshoot it (in osx environment).
It ended up that it is required to have Windows machine as well as Visual Studio.
Please refer this page,
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html

Comment: I don't have windows system. As PhoneGap is cross platform tool, It must provide any out come with this.

Comment: I understand your situation. Maybe try installing Windows in your osx using bootcamp or other 3rd party applications. 
The problem is, even though you could be able to complete your project with Windows supported, you still might need Visual Studio to publish the app to Windows App Store because you don't know if the app will be compiled / built properly in Visual Studio. 
From my experience, there were a lot of trouble with plugin supports, content-security, etc which you wouldn't notice in other environments.